# How to check the accumulated data written by each process

Tags: disk, monitoring, data

I have pihole running on a single board computer and i'm trying to reduce as much as possible data being written to the sd card. I already have logs and pihole database running in a ramdisk but

```
awk '/mmc/ {print $3"\t"$10 / 2 / 1024}' /proc/diskstats
```

tells me that around 80-90MB are being written every day.
I tried `iotop -a` running for 24h and it helps, but the problem is that it only shows running processes. As soon as a process stops, it leaves the list. I still don't know what is writing most of those 80MB.
Is there a way to see which past processes have written to the card and what amount?

Comment: I don't see the kernel keeping such a log. You would have to create it, for example using `iotop -b` or auditing, or directly logging the figures in `/proc/PID/io` (which is probably where iotop mainly gets its data from). Not sure if there is a way to capture processes that run for a short time (sub-second) and generate large amounts of IO. And in the end, most disk writes should come from the buffer cache anyway, which makes it hard to map them to processes. However, is it really necessary to worry about 80MB per day?

Comment: Just a thought.  Have you checked `/etc/fstab` to ensure that your ext3/4 file systems are mounted with `noatime`.  It's a pretty big gotya that out of the box *reading* a file will cause disk writes.  See [man 8 mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) for details.

Comment: @berndbausch I've worked with a fleet of 3000 SBCs in geographically diverse locations where the cost of having an engineer service one is about $200 and they are expected to live at least 10 years.  In that kind of environment you really do want to shave off every MB you can from disk writes.  It's not the board that costs but the engineer to replace it.

Comment: @berndbausch 80MB doesn't seem much for a normal computer but for an 8GB sd card it starts adding up pretty fast. That's 2.5GB per month. `cat /sys/fs/ext4/mmcblk0p1/lifetime_write_kbytes` tells me i already wrote 37GB since i installed armbian 5-6 months ago (granted, i only started using ramdisks less than a month ago). I know SD cards are very cheap and i can literally make an image out of this one and burn it in the new one. But i would prefer to be in control and decrease writes as much as possible. I'm a newbie in everything linux related, hence my question.

Comment: @Philip Couling yep, armian already mounts it with `noatime` by default. I might try disabling journaling because it's writing around 15MB a day. I still don't know how the system will behave after a sudden power loss, like hanging the boot process asking me if i want to scan the disk.